# Wordpress Multisite: Mixing IPs, domains and URL Proxies

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Our company is trying to transition to WordPress Multisite but we have several issues working against us at the moment. We host WP outside our server environment (we use Amazon for our WP sites) so we actually have to use an URL proxy to our Amazon servers. The other issue is that we needed to install Multisite in the root of the folder so the domain is http://100.10.20.30/foldername but we can't proxy that to http://www.domain.com/foldername because that is a live site that we're not moving to WP any time soon. So, of course, the problem we're running in to is that the IP is showing up not only in the source code but in Google now as well (which we don't want).

Does anyone know of anything we can do to keep the IP out of the source code/Google? I was thinking about rewrite rules in the htaccess file but didn't want to do anything until I had some better ideas.

Also, I can't use the domain mapping plugin that everyone seems to suggest for this type of issue because our sites aren't hosted in the root of our server (a prerequisite for the plugin).

So to break it down, this is what we need:

Multisite Parent Blog <-- This has to be the IP address

Multisite child blogs <-- Domain name but when we set the actual proxied domain name in the settings we get a 404 error because it's not looking in the right place. It's looking for an actual folder on our internal servers.

Thanks!

Comment: Found the solution myself. Posted below:

 1. In the Multisite dashboard, click on "All Sites" then administer the
    specific site.
 2. Under the "Path" field, you'll need to deselect the
        "Update siteurl and home as well."
 3. Save changes.  
 4. Click on "Settings" tab.  
 5. Change the URL in the following fields: "SiteURL" and "Home"
 6. Save changes. 

When all is said and done, the IP is showing in the "Info" tab but it changes the URL in the source code to your domain.

Comment: write it as an answer, and accept the answer :) it's a bit cleaner than renaming to RESOLVED and commenting the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution myself. Posted below:

1. In the Multisite dashboard, click on "All Sites" then administer the specific site.
2. Under the "Path" field, you'll need to deselect the "Update siteurl and home as well."
3. Save changes.
4. Click on "Settings" tab.
5. Change the URL in the following fields: "SiteURL" and "Home"
6. Save changes.

When all is said and done, the IP is showing in the "Info" tab but it changes the URL in the source code to your domain.